# PHP uppercase letter in String

Tags: php, uppercase

Like the title says, I'm looking for a way to check if a string contains an uppercase letter in it. It is for a password field, and I cannot use regex because we have not learned any of that yet in class.

I tried to use ctype_upper but that only seems to work if every character in the string is uppercase.

Is there a way to check any character in a string, but not using regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if (strtolower($string) != $string) {
    echo 'You have uppercase in your string';
} else {
    echo 'You have no uppercase in your string';
}
```

This checks if the converted string to lowercase is equal to the original string. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

Use the **strtoupper()** function to transform the string into all uppercase characters that’s capitalized letters, and then compare the transformed string against the original one to see if they are identical. If they are, then you are pretty sure the original string was also a string consisting of ONLY capital letters

```
if (strtoupper($string) == $string) {
echo $string.' is all uppercase letters.';}
```

Comment: "if a string contains an uppercase letter in it." I think OP requires to have atleast a upper case character in string not check whole string as upper case.

Answer (score 0):

function isPartUppercase($string) {     if(preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $string)===0) {        return true;    }   return false; }

The function uses a simple regular expression that tries to find any upper case A-Z characters, preg_match() returns the number of instances of the expression it finds in the string, but stops at 1, preg_match_all() returns the count of all instances it finds.